# Using numpy.linalg with large system of equations

Tags: python, numpy, lapack

I'm stucked trying to use the `numpy.linalg` functions to solve a big system of linear equations.

For instance, I've been trying to use:

```
numpy.linalg.solve
numpy.linalg.cg
numpy.linalg.inv
```

Among others, and none of these functions return anything. The program seems to abort raising no error or warning at all.

To demonstrate, I have this piece of code to create my **A** matrix:

```
   import numpy
   from intertools import product

   indices = numpy.arange(x_steps * y_steps).reshape(x_steps, y_steps)
   a = numpy.zeros((x_steps * y_steps, x_steps * y_steps))
   for x, y in product(range(x_steps), range(y_steps)):
        neighbors_x = indices[x, max(0, y-1):y+2].flatten()
        neighbors_y = indices[max(0, x-1):x+2, y].flatten()
        current = indices[x, y]

        a[current, neighbors_x] = 1.0
        a[current, neighbors_y] = 1.0
        a[current, current] = -4.0

    h = (x_dim / x_steps) * (y_dim / y_steps)
    a /= h
```

With`x_dim = y_dim = 12` and `x_steps = y_steps = 100`.

The code works just fine. When I try to calculate `det(A)` I get `0.0144`, which is correct.

But the system is never solved.
Then I tried to calculate the inverse of `A`:

```
print 'inv'
z = numpy.linalg.inv(a)
print 'here'
```

And `'here'` is never printed, and **no error is raised at all**. I see the first print and then it appears on the console **The program finished with code 0**. As I said, I tried to solve the system with the conjugate gradient method too and the same occurs. It is weird, because I didn't get any error/warning to help me to find what is wrong.

I strongly think this is a memory problem (I am running my code in a 64bits Windows 8.1 -- 4GB RAM -- with a 32bits Numpy -- 64 generated a lot of incompatibilities here) but I really don't know if there is a way to solve it. If that is the problem, the Conjugate gradient method shouldn't be able to solve this, since that is its purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've run your code on my notebook (Win7, I5, 64bit, 8GB RAM) and Python 3.4. After a minute or so I got a finite result for 'z'. However, it required quite some RAM. The RAM usage increased by about 1.5GB during calculation. You might check how much RAM is left on your machine before you start the calculation.

Comment: I'll do that, @RaJa. Thank you.

Comment: But the conjugate gradient method should require less RAM, doesn't it, @RaJa? Even this method I can't run.

Comment: I tried your code on a different machine and it also worked. However, the determinant of the matrix 'a' in your example is calculated to 'inf'. Is the uppercase 'A' the same as the lower case 'a'? I was also not able to find a numpy version of the conjugate gradient method. There is one in the sparse linear algebra module of scipy. Have you tried to solve your system of equations numerically by using 'lsqr' from the same module?
Could you post an example of your solution vector b (A.x = b)?

Comment: Hi, @RaJa. In my machine I get the det(a) (det(A), indeed) == 0.0144. You're right, it is a scipy module. No, I'll try this method. So far I can't post any example of a solution because I couldn't run it. :S

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding :\ I mean, if you could post the vector b that is on the right side of your equation system (A.x = b).